# Understanding of Android ripple animation

Tags: android, animation, material-design, ripple

I want to create an animation like  material ripple animation, so I decided to look at its source code.

1. The enter point is :
   `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">`
   go to: **Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\data\res\values\attrs.xml**

   ```
    <!-- Background drawable for bordered standalone items that need focus/pressed states. -->
    <attr name="selectableItemBackground" format="reference" />
   ```
2. Next we go into **Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\data\res\values\themes.xml**

```
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/item_background</item>
```

Nothing special, just another drawable.

3. Next in: **Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\data\res\drawable\item_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will  invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

</selector
```

4. We are close, in this file we saw drawables of different states. Transition file at:
   **Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\data\res\drawable\list_selector_background_transition.xml** is:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background_pressed"  />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background_longpress"  />
</transition>
```

Finaly we have 4 files, in picture below
[image]

So the questions is:

1. How this 4 squares turns into this circular ripple animation?
2. That means this black pointers?
3. what the orange fill and green border do ?
4. (optional) Where is the magic part?